# Use global parent selector with Sass and CSS Module

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

How can I style my React component using Sass and CSS modules based on the existence of a GLOBAL parent selector (in this case isOpen)?

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="isOpen">
   <div class="MyContainer__MyStyle___u9dTa">
      My react component
   </div>
</div>
```

My Sass file:

```
.MyStyle
   margin-left: 100px
   color: black

// TODO: Override MyStyle if 'isOpen' is on parent, e.g. something like:
.MyStyle
   :global(.isOpen) &
      margin-left: 0
      color: red
```

The code above gives error: Property "global" must be followed by a ':'

Comment: Your code doesn't give me errors but the output is strange. I don't understand very well your question, you want something like this? http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e221cca9fdf3ff44c355f128ddc49f3b

Comment: CSS Modules hasn't achieved this yet even using `:external()`.

Answer (score 11):

Though it's a little late for me to answer, I think I found the answer and I'll post it for those who may encounter this problem in the future.

The problem is in Sass you have to escape the `:global` keyword with `\:global` in order to make CSS module works as you expected.

The discussion can be found at https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/448.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have a few issues here.

"MyContainer__MyStyle___u9dTa" is one big class name. You cannot reference one part by using the period syntax. however you can reference a partial class like this..

```
*[class=*"MyStyle"]{}
```

It also looks like you are using LESS syntax instead of sass. here is how i would write the code with sass and partial class references

```
*[class=*"MyStyle"]{
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: black;
}
// TODO: Override MyStyle if 'isOpen' is on parent, e.g. something like:
.isOpen{
    *[class=*"MyStyle"]{
        margin-left: 0
        color: red
    }
}
```

good luck. and its worth noting that you can use vanilla CSS within a sass file if that is easier for you.  Here are some resources for CSS and SASS

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/